# Java String separation

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder, stringtokenizer

I am stuck trying to get the desired output. Its actually a string separation problem I am facing in the another problem.

```
// Inputs
        String input1 = "=DIVIDE(Input!RC,Input!R[1]C)"; // B1
        String input2 = "=DIVIDE(MULTIPLY(Input!R[-1]C,Input!R[1]C),100)"; // B2
        String input3 = "=Input!R[-2]C + R[-1]C"; // B3
        String input4 = "=DIVIDE(R[-2]C,Input!R[-2]C)"; // B4
        String input5 = "=R[-4]C+R[-1]C"; // B5
```

Now, here I have to replace RC with proper B value.

Example for input5, I will look at R[-4]C and then since its input5, I will add (-4) and (5) to get 1 and I will replace R[-4]C with B1.

Its going to be same for all.

```
// Desired output
        // =DIVIDE(Input!B1,Input!B2)
        // =DIVIDE(MULTIPLY(Input!B1,Input!B3),100)
        // =Input!B1+calc!B2
        // =DIVIDE(calc!B2,Input!B2)
        // =calc!B1+calc!B4
```

Can anyone give me some idea how I can achieve this ?

Comment: Can there be 2-digit numbers?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Use a regular expression to find RC or R[(\d)]C, extract the number and add it to the value you want.

Comment: You might want to look at real parsers (lexers), to me this looks like a language and not just string manipulation...

Comment: i am dealing with google spreadsheets api here, and yes i have tried my bit, but i wanted to get some idea from others.

Comment: I was thinking of regular expressions too. but i have always had difficulty dealing with them

Comment: @RohitJain Yes there can be. R and C's denote rows and columns in the spreadsheet

Answer (score 1):

Here's is some idea:

```
identify offset (1 for input1, 2 for input2 etc)
for each match of "R" ( "[" DIGIT+ "]" )? "C"
  if DIGIT+ != "" then <index> = offset + tonumber(DIGIT+) else <index> = offset
  replace match with B<index>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the idea

```
static String replaceB(String s, int n) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\W(R(\\[(.+?)\\])?C)").matcher(s);
    for (; m.find(); m.reset(s)) {
        String r = "B" + (m.group(3) == null ? n : n + Integer.parseInt(m.group(3)));
        if (!r.startsWith("!")) {
            r = "calc!" + r;
        }
        s = s.replace(m.group(1), r);
    }
    return "B" + n + s;
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    String input1 = "=DIVIDE(Input!RC,Input!R[1]C)"; // B1
    String input2 = "=DIVIDE(MULTIPLY(Input!R[-1]C,Input!R[1]C),100)"; // B2
    String input3 = "=Input!R[-2]C + R[-1]C"; // B3
    String input4 = "=DIVIDE(R[-2]C,Input!R[-2]C)"; // B4
    String input5 = "=R[-4]C+R[-1]C"; // B5
    System.out.println(replaceB(input1, 1));
    System.out.println(replaceB(input2, 2));
    System.out.println(replaceB(input3, 3));
    System.out.println(replaceB(input4, 4));
    System.out.println(replaceB(input5, 5));
}
```

prints

```
B1=DIVIDE(Input!B1,Input!B2)
B2=DIVIDE(MULTIPLY(Input!B1,Input!B3),100)
B3=Input!B1 + calc!B2
B4=DIVIDE(calc!B2,Input!B2)
B5=calc!B1+calc!B4
```

Comment: Sorry I have edited the input and output part in the question, please check. My bad.

Comment: fixed, looks very much like yours now

Comment: sorry i made a change again. it was a mistake in the input. now i have a proper input. when there is nothing before RC it appends calc! to it